# "undefined symbol: synctex_next_result" when editors try to use SyncTex

Tags: forward-inverse-search

When I start texmaker on the Linux commandline, this happens immediatly:

```
$ texmaker 
texmaker: symbol lookup error: texmaker: undefined symbol: synctex_next_result
```

Similarly, when enabling SyncTex in the gummi editor when it's already running and then trying to build a document:

```
$ gummi
[Info] ...
gummi: symbol lookup error: gummi: undefined symbol: synctex_next_result
```

Using SyncTex in Gummi only stopped working a few days ago. Changing to a different engine doesn't solve the problem. I'm using the TeX Live 2018/dev/Debian installed via apt on Linux Mint 18. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which Linux distribution and version of Texmaker and Gummi are you using? Did you install TeX Live using the package manager of your distribution or [manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/3323), and which version?

Comment: Gummi is the up-to-date version (just says gummi git in the version information). Texlive is TeX Live 2018/dev/Debian.

Comment: I'm not sure we're going to be much help if Debian have got hold of a time machine and are bringing you back software from the future. Perhaps they'd care to share? Would save a lot of bother next year getting everything together.

Comment: The version number of TeX Live is strange indeed, the official Linux Mint repository currently includes TeX Live 2015. Is that really correct, and if so, from which repository did you get it? Anyway, I suspect the problem is a broken/incompatible version of `libsynctex1` - try reinstalling it using `apt-get install --reinstall libsynctex1`. If that doesn't help, what is the output of `ldd $(which gummi) | grep synctex`?

Comment: Reinstalling didn't help. `ldd $(which gummi) | grep synctex` yielded `libsynctex.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsynctex.so.1 (0x00007f900e4b2000)`

Comment: @FelixRindt That looks alright, so `gummi` seems to load the right library, then let's see wether the library actually contains the required symbol: `nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsynctex.so.1 | grep synctex_next_result`

Comment: `$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsynctex.so.1 | grep next`:
    `0000000000010190 T synctex_iterator_has_next`,
   `00000000000101d0 T synctex_iterator_next_result`,
    `00000000000084d0 T _synctex_node_next`,
   `00000000000083c0 T synctex_node_next`,
    `0000000000010980 T synctex_scanner_next_result`
It did not list `synctex_next_result` itself.

Comment: @FelixRindt Well, that seems to be SyncTeX 1.19 or 1.20, which is currently in development and incompatible with your version of Texmaker/Gummi. While you can try installing the necessary older version with `sudo apt-get install libsynctex1=2015.20160222.37495-1`, I suspect this is coming from the same development repository you used to install TeX Live as well (which one exactly that is you didn't tell us yet) - I suggest removing that one and downgrading all packages to the versions from the official Ubuntu/Mint repository if you want to have a stable user experience.

Comment: Thanks @diabonas I reinstalled texlive from the Ubuntu repository. Was a bit tricky to get all packages in a valid state, but it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

As I installed packages using a PPA, my synctex was too new for the rest of my texlive distribution.  I solved by reinstalling texlive using the default ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade libsynctex1.
i did it with aptitude.

```
sudo apt install aptitude
aptitude versions libsynctex1
sudo aptitude install libsynctex1=2015.20160222.37495-1
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the same for me, i was try to reconfigure texmaker package and re-install it, but they not run,
it is the problem, it is because a bug

" The latest update of libsynctex1 broke the ABI "

you can read about

https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/6XNBKiiV_jw#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/6XNBKiiV_jw

https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=msg/linux.debian.bugs.dist/6XNBKiiV_jw/xW8MvAskAAAJ#!msg/linux.debian.bugs.dist/6XNBKiiV_jw/xW8MvAskAAAJ

Answer (score 0):

For debian distribution and based in debian:

you need to dowmgrade to old stable version of libsynctex1 and Texmaker run fine again,

package manager: aptitude

texmaker depend of libsynctex1 (any version)

texmaker: 5.0.2-1+b1

[DOWNGRADE] libsynctex1: 2018.20180416.47457-1 -> 2014.20140926.35254-6