# Undefined symbol: synctex_next_result when starting Texmaker

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I have been a years long user of LaTeX with Texmaker.
I use Ubuntu 16.04.
Suddenly since last week when I start Texmaker I get:

> symbol lookup error: texmaker: undefined symbol: synctex_next_result

I have fully reinstalled TeX Live, did not help,
I reinstalled synctex, did not help.
I tried starting up Texmaker with `-synctex=0` and `-1`, did not help.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This looks very similar to [“undefined symbol: synctex_next_result” when editors try to use SyncTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392278/3323). In that case, it turned out the user had installed a development version of TeX Live from a PPA which included a SyncTeX too recent for Texmaker. So the question is: how did you install TeX Live (manually or using your package manager), and which version is it? Which version is `libsynctex1` (can be obtained by executing `dkpg -s libsynctex1`)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem mostly likely lies with incompatible package versions of Texmaker and SyncTeX installed on the system and the OP hasn't provided necessary information to further debug the issue.