# Texmaker doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: texmaker

I have tried `sudo apt-get install texmaker`, I have tried the software center, I have tried downloading the latest version from their website and everything results in the exact same behavior, I try to run texmaker and then it disappears from the toolbar.

I am not sure if this is a new thing or not because nothing suggested from other sources online has worked for me.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) since other Ubuntu users does not seem to have any problems, could you a bit (or a lot) more specific. Have you tried running it from a terminal? Just run the command `texmaker`. Note, run it in a terminal, not as `run command ` (that is via the F keys or something, I never use `run command `). Running it from a terminal may reveal a lot more details as to why it fails

Comment: I get this error: `texmaker: symbol lookup error: texmaker: undefined symbol: synctex_next_result`

Comment: Did you google the error? I got this hit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392278/3929

Comment: I apologize for the late comment, but I am not sure exactly how to resolve this issue. In that question, no information is given as to what version of texlive I need to install and how to remove texlive from my computer without causing any conflicts. I installed texworks and it works fine, I do not understand why I need to install an older version to make texmaker work. Why hasn't texmaker updated itself, or is there some version out there already that I am missing out?

Comment: I don't use it so cannot help there. It sounds quite strange that it would not work of the bat. But I have had several windows users who went back to version 4.5 because they did not like version 5 (either the look, or because the viewer crashed oncertain docs). Have you given texstudio a try (it has the same base idea as texmaker but more features)

Answer (score 1):

Your libsynctex1 package is too recent thus texmaker does not recognize it.
Install aptitude then lookup the version then downgrade it as below:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
aptitude versions libsynctex1
sudo aptitude install libsynctex1=2015.20160222.37495-1
```